# Cache put item concurrency and throughput

Tags: caching, web, redis, dns, memcached

Most CDN servers use caching for frequently accessed contents.

**Scenario:**
Lets suppose someone uploaded a very trending pic and many users (1000) from same location trying to access that pic.

**Question:**
Lets say webserver receives a  request first checks it cache and it found content miss for that pic and pull the content from CDN.If pull takes lets say x secs and server got 999 more request meanwhile for the same content.

Would server fetch content 999 more times from server (as server still pulling data and there is no data in cache) and update cache?

If not what schemes server implements to avoid these kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a lock on the server side to avoid too many requests to CDN.

When server receives a request:

1. the working thread checks if the key exist. If key exists, return the value.
2. If key doesn't exist, i.e. cache miss, the working thread tries to lock a mutex.
3. If locking successfully, this working thread fetches data from CDN, update the cache, and unlock the mutex.
4. If this thread fails to lock the mutex, i.e. some other thread is sending request to CDN, it sleeps some time, e.g. 1 second, and goes to step 1 to retry the whole process.

If you have many servers, and the cache is shared among these servers, i.e. multiple processes. You can use a distributed lock, e.g. Redis' `SETNX`.

However, in that case, you need to be careful with **step 3**: If the server locks successfully, but crashes before unlocking. Other servers will wait forever. So you also need to set an expiration for the lock.